# Any additional settings for express-session secure cookies on Heroku besides trust proxy?

Tags: heroku, cookies, express-session

I'm trying to set-up secure cookies on an express app running on Heroku. I've tried both `app.set('trust proxy', true)` and setting `proxy: true` in the session config. In both cases, the cookie fails to be modified once deployed to Heroku using an SSL cert.

Other things: I never implemented `resave = true` in the session since mongo-connect has a touch method.

```
userSessionStore = new MongoDBStore({
url: 'foo',
collection: 'bar',
touchAfter: 3600,
});

const sess = {
  secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
  name: 'name',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true,
  cookie: {
    maxAge: 1 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000
  },
  store: userSessionStore
};

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  sess.cookie = {
    secure: true,
    httpOnly: true,
    domain: baseURL
  };
}

app.use(session(sess));

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  app.set('trust proxy', true);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was due to the baseURL variable not matching both the host and the subdomain on heroku. Since heroku hosts many apps at foo.herokuapp.com, matching the subdomain is required.